# Visual Studio 2022 - toolbar button for 'start new debug instance'?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If you want to run a debug instance of the currently-selected project in Visual Studio ***without changing the startup project***, you can bind a keyboard shortcut to `ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance`.  But I can't seem to find an equivalent way to add a toolbar button to do this.

Is there a way to get this behaviour from clicking a toolbar button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this in the end using the [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension (which is pretty awesome, by the way).  Created a new command for the button, and that command can then be added as a button to the toolbar.  The command navigates to the desired project in the Solution Explorer and runs the currently-selected project, much like the keyboard shortcut does, allowing you to have a button that runs a particular project without changing the default configured startup project:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        var projectLocation = @"MyProject\DB\MyProject.DBMigrator";
        DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate();

        dynamic marshaler = DTE.ActiveWindow.Object;
        try {
            marshaler.GetItem(projectLocation).Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException) {
            var sbError = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sbError.AppendLine("Couldn't find project: " + projectLocation);
            sbError.AppendLine("(try manually navigating to it in Solution Explorer at least once first...)");
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(sbError.ToString());
            return;
        }
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.StartNewInstance");
    }
}
```